# How to remove and update a XML tag in xml2js

Tags: node.js, xml2js

How can I edit XML file by `xml2js`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
var fn = 'file.xml';
fs.readFile(fn, function(err, data) {
   parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
       //result.data[3].removeChild(); ?????
       //result.date[2].name.innerText = 'Raya'; ?????
   });
});
```

This is not working!

Comment: `data` is a JavaScript object, not a DOM tree. See [this](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a property from a JavaScript object, simply set the property to undefined:

```
result.name = undefined;
```

Result from xml2js:

```
{
    "name": "I will get deleted",
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Item 1",
            "itemLocation": "item1.htm"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Item 2",
            "itemLocation": "item2.htm",
        }
    ]
}
```

After setting to undefined:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Item 1",
            "itemLocation": "item1.htm"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Item 2",
            "itemLocation": "item2.htm",
        }
    ]
}
```

For you, this would be

```
result.data[3] == undefined;
```

Tip: you can use JSON.stringify to help you.

Comment: what if you are interested in removing a parent tag while you mantain the child tag? lets say you have <a> <b></b> </a> I want to remove <a> but continue to have <b>.. it would not work this the following approach.

Comment: You can try to use a simple find and replace, or a regex replace, and assign the value back to the property (like I did above).